# Why could non-GitHub user push changes to GitHub Public Repo?

Tags: git, authentication, github

I have a GitHub.com Public Repo for personal use. My GitHub user account is having gmail id. Later When I started to work in Azure DevOps Git Repo of my employer, I have changed email and username in my local machine to Bussiness mail and DevOps username  globally.

```
$ git --version 
git version 2.23.0.windows.1
```

I have installed Git Credential Manager for windows few months before.

In my Personal GitHub Repo, I haven't added my business email as collaborator. Neither have GitHub account with Business mail id. But I could commit changes locally and push changes to GitHub personal Repo with business mail/username.

How is it possible ? Does GitHub authenticate my business mail/username using OAuth/OpenID kind of stuff?   Can anybody push changes to a Public Repo in GitHub.com without GitHub account/without being added as a collaborator?

Comment: Note that the email address in commits (Commiter and Author) are unrelated to the user authentication done on GitHub. So what happened is *probably* that you created commits with your business email as the commiter and pushed it to GitHub using your personal credentials.

Comment: @JoachimSauer gave you the good answer ;) When you set your email in git, that's more something informative which is used when creating commits (you could set whatever you want). Having push rights to a repository have nothing to do with the email config set in git config.

Comment: But Under Insights tab, Pulse section shows my commits with business mail as separate author with DevOps Username. GitHub didn't count those commits as my commits. In my GitHub profile page Contribution Calendar graph not showing those commits

Comment: The reason for not counting those commits is here. https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile